# Scala - write unit tests for objects/singletons that extends a trait/class with DB connection

Tags: unit-testing, scala, mocking, typesafe

Unit test related question

Encountered a problem with testing scala objects that extend another trait/class that has a DB connection (or any other "external" call)

Using a singleton with a DB connection anywhere in my project makes unit-test not be a option because I cannot override / mock the DB connection

This results in changing my design only for test purpose in situations where its clearly needed to be a object

Any suggestions ?

Code snippet for a non testable code :

```
object How2TestThis extends SomeDBconnection {

  val somethingUsingDB = {
    getStuff.map(//some logic)
  }

  val moreThigs {
    //more things
  }

}

trait SomeDBconnection {
  import DBstuff._
  val db = connection(someDB)  
  val getStuff = db.getThings
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. One of the options is to use cake pattern to require some DB connection and mixin specific implementation as desired. For example:

   ```
   import java.sql.Connection

   // Defines general DB connection interface for your application
   trait DbConnection {
     def getConnection: Connection
   }

   // Concrete implementation for production/dev environment for example
   trait ProductionDbConnectionImpl extends DbConnection {
     def getConnection: Connection = ???
   }

   // Common code that uses that DB connection and needs to be tested.
   trait DbConsumer {
     this: DbConnection =>

     def runDb(sql: String): Unit = {
       getConnection.prepareStatement(sql).execute()
     }
   }

   ...

   // Somewhere in production code when you set everything up in init or main you
   // pick concrete db provider
   val prodDbConsumer = new DbConsumer with ProductionDbConnectionImpl
   prodDbConsumer.runDb("select * from sometable")

   ...

   // Somewhere in test code you mock or stub DB connection ...
   val testDbConsumer = new DbConsumer with DbConnection { def getConnection = ??? }
   testDbConsumer.runDb("select * from sometable")
   ```

   If you have to use a singleton/Scala `object` you can have a `lazy val` or some `init(): Unit` method that sets connection up.
2. Another approach would be to use some sort of injector. For example look at Lift code:

   ```
   package net.liftweb.http

   /**
    * A base trait for a Factory.  A Factory is both an Injector and
    * a collection of FactorMaker instances.  The FactoryMaker instances auto-register
    * with the Injector.  This provides both concrete Maker/Vender functionality as
    * well as Injector functionality.
    */
   trait Factory extends SimpleInjector
   ```

   Then somewhere in your code you use this vendor like this:

   ```
   val identifier = new FactoryMaker[MongoIdentifier](DefaultMongoIdentifier) {}
   ```

   And then in places where you actually have to get access to DB:

   ```
   identifier.vend
   ```

   You can supply alternative provider in tests by surrounding your code with:

   ```
   identifier.doWith(mongoId) { <your test code> }
   ```

   which can be conveniently used with specs2 `Around` context for example:

   ```
   implicit val dbContext new Around {
     def around[T: AsResult](t: => T): Result = {
       val mongoId = new MongoIdentifier {
         def jndiName: String = dbName
       }
       identifier.doWith(mongoId) {
         AsResult(t)
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   It's pretty cool because it's implemented in Scala without any special bytecode or JVM hacks.
3. If you think first 2 options are too complicated and you have a small app you can use `Properties` file/cmd args to let you know if you are running in test or production mode. Again the idea comes from Lift :). You can easily implement it yourself, but here how you can do it with Lift `Props`:

   ```
   // your generic DB code:
   val jdbcUrl: String = Props.get("jdbc.url", "jdbc:postgresql:database")
   ```

   You can have 2 props files:

   - production.default.props

     `jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql:database`
   - test.default.props

     `jdbc.url=jdbc:h2`

   Lift will automatically detect run mode `Props.mode` and pick the right props file to read. You can set run mode with JVM cmd args.

   So in this case you can either connect to in-memory DB or just read run mode and set your connection in code accordingly (mock, stub, uninitialized, etc).
4. Use regular IOC pattern - pass dependencies via constructor arguments to the class. Don't use an `object`. This gets inconvenient quickly unless you use special dependency injection frameworks.

Some suggestions:

Use `object` for something that can't have an alternative implementation and if this only implementation will work in all environments. Use `object` for constants and pure FP non side effecting code. Use singletons for wiring things up at the last moment - like a class with `main`, not somewhere deep in the code where many components depend on it unless it has no side effects or it uses something like stackable/injectable vendor providers (see Lift).

Conclusion:

You can't mock an object or override its implementation. You need to design your code to be testable and some of the options for it are listed above. It's a good practice to make your code flexible with easily composable parts not only for the purposes of testing but also for reusability and maintainability.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969225/dependency-injection-with-scala

Comment: problem is i dont want any DB connection (not test not h2) for my unit testing i will want to mock a db call and return a json result for example this solution is a good 1 for integration tests but not for methods unit testing

Comment: First 2 options let you mock the db/connection in tests. If you use Cake pattern you just mix in a mocked db, and if you use some sort of injector then you can inject any kind of mocked db.