# Injecting database methods from the service layer to the storage layer

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, slick

Our app has a service layer on top of a storage layer - a service layer method will create a new database session (we're using [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/) on top of MySql) and passes the session as an implicit parameter to the storage layer methods

```
trait Service1 {
  def serviceLayerMethod(params) = {
    db withSession {
      implicit session: Session =>
        storageLayerMethod1(params)
        storageLayerMethod2(params)
}}}

object DAO1 {
  def storageLayerMethod1(params)(implicit session: Session)
}

object DAO2 {
 def storageLayerMethod2(params)(implicit session: Session)
}
```

We'd like to be able to inject different method implementations from the service layer to the storage layer, for example we have a `multiGet` method that retrieves multiple records, and we'd like to have different implementations of this method e.g. one that does the `multiGet` in parallel and another that attempts to retrieve data from the Redis cache before pulling it from the database.  I could pass these methods around as implicit parameters, but I was hoping that there was a way to do this with less boilerplate.

```
trait MultiGet {
  def multiGet(params)(implicit session: Session)
}

object MultiGetDefault extends MultiGet
object MultiGetParallel extends MultiGet
object MultiGetCached extends Multiget

trait Servic1 {
  def serviceLayerMethod1(params) = {
    db withSession {
      implicit session: Session =>
        storageLayerMethod1(params)(MultiGetDefault)
  }}

  def serviceLayerMethod2(params) = {
    db withSession {
      implicit session: Session =>
        storageLayerMethod1(params)(MultiGetParallel)
}}}

object DAO1 {
  def storageLayerMethod1(params)(implicit session: Session, multiGetImpl: MultiGet) {
    multiGetImpl.multiGet(params)
}}
```

Most of the storage layer methods are in singleton objects, so I'm not able to mixin different `MultiGet` implementations without a significant refactor.  The service layer traits are being instantiated/injected at the controller layer via the cake pattern.

Comment: Maybe this answer would suit your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965848/scala-write-unit-tests-for-objects-singletons-that-extends-a-trait-class-with

Answer (score 0):

We're going to try extending/wrapping `Session` with a version that implements `multiGet` etc

```
trait MySession extends Session {
  private val session: Session

  def capabilities = session.capabiliites
  def close = session.close
  def conn = session.conn
  ...

  def multiGet(tableName: String, ids: Seq[Int])
}

class DefaultSession(private val session: Session) extends MySession {
  def multiGet(tableName: String, ids: Seq[Int]) // default implementation
}

class ConcurrentSession(private val session: Session) extends MySession {
  def multiGet(tableName: String, ids: Seq[Int]) // concurrent implementation
}

def defaultExecute[T](fun: (MySession) => T): T = db withSession {
  _session: Session =>
    fun(new DefaultSession(_session))
}

def concurrentExecute[T](fun: (MySession) => T): T = db withSession {
  _session: Session =>
    fun(new ConcurrentSession(_session))
}
```