# Change persistence layer dynamically (upon runtime) with as few changes as possible

Tags: java, scala, design-patterns, dependency-injection, persistence

I am searching for a design pattern/way to exchange a (persistence) layer of my application dynamically (preferably even at runtime).

**Why?**

I'd like to be able to decide whether to save certain data to XML or a database on a "per instance"-basis. So I may decide that one project uses XML as a backend and another uses a database. I want to be *flexible* here and to be able to easily add another **"driver"** for e.g. Json or whatever.

Now assume the following setup:

We have a controller and we want to manage some data. We can choose between a SQL and XML implementation.

One possible (working) solution:

BasicController.scala

```
val myPersistenceLayer: PersistenceLayer = SQLPersistenceLayer

val apples: Seq[Apple] = myPersistenceLayer.getApples()

trait PersistenceLayer
{
    def getApples(): Seq[Apple]
    def getBananas(): Seq[Banana]
}

object SQLPersistenceLayer extends PersistenceLayer
{
    override def getApples(): Seq[Apple] = {...}
    override def getBananas(): Seq[Banana] = {...}
}
```

This is a rather nasty solution as one would have to add methods for each new Model (think fruit! ;)) not only in the trait, but also in every implementation. I like my single responsibility so I'd rather delegate that to the models instead, like:

```
trait PersistenceLayer
{
    def getAll(model: Model): Seq[Model] = { model.getAll() }
}

trait Model
{
    def getAll(): Seq[Model]
}

package "SQL"

class Apple extends Model
{
    def getAll(): Seq[Apple] = { // do some SQL magic here }
}

package "XML"

class Apple extends Model
{
    def getAll(): Seq[Apple] = { // do some XML magic here instead }
}
```

Now the big problem here is, even if I implement a concrete PersistenceLayer, like so:

```
object SQLPersistenceLayer extends PersistenceLayer {}
```

how could I tell the application to use the model of the right package?

If I use the SQLPersistenceLayer upon:

```
val apples = myPersistenceLayer.get(Apple)
```

I would need to import the right "Apple" class, which defeats the whole purpose because then I could just remove all other classes, import the right one and just use a generic "getAll()" method on it.

So again I would need to change the implementation at multiple lines, which is what I want to avoid.

I thought about something like giving a string with the package-name, like

val package = "sql" and in the controller to import it from the right package, but this is not really feasible and not really easy to accomplish and it's a rather nasty hack for something I'm obviously missing.

**To make a long story short: I want to be able to switch the package to use for my persistence needs *dynamically*. In some dynamically typed languages I could come up with a solution, but not in Scala or any statically typed language, so I guess I'm not knowing a certain design pattern here**

** Edit **

A thought occurred (ya, sometimes it happens ;)) and now I'm wondering whether something like this could lead to what I want:

```
namespace tld.app.persistence

trait PersistenceLayer
{
    proteced val models: mutable.HashMap[String, Model] = new mutable.HashMap[String, Model]

    def registerModel(key: String, model: Model): Unit =
    {
        models.remove(key)
        models.put(key, model)
    }

    def get(model: String): Seq[Future[Model]] =
    {
        val m: Model = models.getOrElse(model, throw new Exception("No such model found!"))
        m.get
    }   
}

trait Model
{
    def get(): Seq[Future[Model]]
}

namespace tld.app.persistence.sql

object SQLPersistenceLayer extends PersistenceLayer

class Person extends Model
{
    def get(): Seq[Future[Model]] =
    {
        // ... query the database
    }
}

namespace tld.app.persistence.xml

object XMLPersistenceLayer extends PersistenceLayer

class Person extends Model
{
    def get(): Seq[Future[Model]] =
    {
        // ... read in from the appropriate xml-file
    }
}

object Settings
{
    var persistenceLayer: PersistenceLayer = SQLPersistenceLayer // Default is SQLPersistenceLayer
}

Somewhere in the application:

Settings.persistenceLayer.get("person")

// Then a user-interaction happens

Settings.persistenceLayer = XMLPersistenceLayer

Settings.persistenceLayer.get("person")
```

The persistenceLayer *normally* stays the same, but the user can decide upon changing it. I'll have a deeper look at it, as soon as I can find time. But maybe somebody immediately spots a problem with that approach.

Comment: The interface of `PersistenceLayer` in your requirements looks weird, what would be an argument to `getAll`?

Comment: A concrete model from either sql or xml namespace that has to extend another trait ("model" - of course) so that the actual logic is delegated to the (concrete) models.

Comment: The semantics of getAll() method does not imply an input parameter, you're interested in a type. This suggests to me that you're leaking an implementation detail (reflection to decide on appropriate implementation inside a method). Moreover, when `getAll` returns `Seq[Model]` you are loosing even this type.

Comment: > In some dynamically typed languages...
1. [Rapture](http://rapture.io/) does use `language.dynamics` to achieve similar mechanisms.
2. implicits (using [Type Classes](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html) or not) may help you too, as it was mentioned
3. in FP, you can pass a function as a parameter, that implements a specific behavior, to a bland method/function (or even return a function). So I'd try to select such a (set of) function(s) in the settings; that is, the *behavior* about apples or oranges (same applies to xml or sql).

Comment: Regarding  your edit: having a mutable global switch of persistence mechanism will inevitably yield surprising results in multi-threaded context. Then again, what you read is a `Model`, not `Person`.

Answer (score 2):

DI allows you to wire an implementation at compile time. There are many ways to do DI in Scala (Cake Pattern, Reader Monad, DI frameworks, etc).

If you want to wire the dependency on application startup then regular dependency mechanisms would work. You would just create an instance of desired dependency (SQL, XML) based on some condition and pass it to the code.

If you want to keep switching between dependencies during your application execution, i.e. sometimes you save to SQL, other times to XML then you can use something similar to [Lift Injector](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-8.2.html), see also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965848/scala-write-unit-tests-for-objects-singletons-that-extends-a-trait-class-with) - option 2.

Comment: Yes, I want DI at runtime (being able to switch dependencies during application execution). I'll see how I can manually achieve this. Not eager to load in a framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can use runtime reflection to accomplish it. You need to specify and create class/object at runtime which you'll be passing to Persistency layer and then just call generic `getAll` method.

For details of reflection library -> http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html

It would be better to make companion object `Apple` which has `getAll` method implemented differently for each persistency layer.

Then access Apple objects with reflection by using full package name

```
val apple:sql.Apple = //Reflection library object access
val apple:xml.Apple = //Reflection library object access


val apples = myPersistenceLayer.get(apple)
```

Comment: then again I would need to change all occurrences of "apple:xml.Apple=" to the appropriate type. I just want to change one line or load it at runtime from a config file and be done with it.

Comment: Your comment suggests that you are fine with compile-time implementation wiring, not necessarily runtime?

Comment: What I want to do: The user may change the type of persistence at any given time. Standard is sql, but if he prefers, it can be switched to XML. All the logic has to still work then. Please see my update above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve module-based inclusion with implicits + TypeTags with something along these lines

```
object SqlPersistence {
  implicit def getAll[T: TypeTag](): Seq[T] = {/* type-based sql implementation*/}
}

object JsonPersistence {
  implicit def getAll[T: TypeTag](): Seq[T] = {/* type-based json implementation*/}
}

object PersistenceLayer {
  def getAll[T](implicit getter: Unit => Seq[T]): Seq[T] = getter
}

// somewhere else ...
import SqlPersistence._

PersistenceLayer.getAll[Apple]
```

The advantage is that you can decide on your persistence layer at the spot by bringing a corresponding import. The major downside is the same: you need to decide on your persistence layer with every call and make sure that it is what you think. Also, from my personal experience compiler is less helpful with tricky implicit corner cases, so there is a potential to spend more time debugging.

If you set your persistence layer once for an app, then DI would do fine, e.g. [cake pattern](http://jonasboner.com/2008/10/06/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/). But then again, you either need to have a method per class or resort to reflection. Without reflection, it may look like that:

```
trait PersistenceLayer {
  def getApples(): Apples
}

trait SqlPersistenceLayer extends PersistenceLayer {
  override def getApples() = // sql to get apples 
}

trait Controller {
  this: PersistenceLayer =>

  def doMyAppleStuff = getApples()
}

// somewhere in the main ...
val controller = new Controller with SqlPersistence {}
controller.doMyAppleStuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Something similar is [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) if that helps.

Comment: Please consider adding more details to your answer. Just a link pointing to another website is not considered a good answer. Nonetheless, thank you!

Comment: Sure. I believe Wikipedia has it in details, it would just be repeating the same thing here. I will it a shot though. In your case, I think you could have an abstract persistence layer and two or more implementations of that, one for DB persistence and another for XML persistence. Whichever layer you need can be chosen at runtime. This is Java snippet from Wikipedia-

Comment: Sorry, the example is a little large, but please take a look at the examples on the link.

Answer (score 0):

I think the repository pattern is your solution.

**EDIT:**

*ok. thanks for "-1" thats ok because i did not explained my idea behind...*

> my example is only one of many others. so i hope that this is usefull for someone out there

i will try to explain my idea about using the repository and factory pattern.

for this i made a github repository with the example code: https://github.com/StefanHeimberg/stackoverflow-32319416

my setup ist nearly the same as in your question. but the difference is the following:

- i did not use scala. but the concept would be the same...
- my settings contains only a "flag" for the repository factory.
- the "model" objects are persistence ignorance. that means the do not know how the are persisted. this is the concern of the repositories
- i made dependency injection by hand cause this should be sufficient for the example
- i have no "Controller" but i have "Application Services"...

the decition about the implementation used is made inside the factory on each call to the create() method.

the domain layer does not know anything about the used infrastructure implementation. the application layer is orchestrating the domain service and the infrastructure services (in my example only the repositories)

if you have any DI Container then the factory could by a Producer or soething else... depends on DI Container

**package structure:**

[image]

i have also made a simple integration test

```
public class AppleServiceIT {

    private Settings settings;
    private AppleService appleService;

    @Before
    public void injectDependencies() {
        settings = new Settings();
        final JdbcAppleRepository jdbcAppleRepository = new JdbcAppleRepository();
        final JsonAppleRepository jsonAppleRepository = new JsonAppleRepository();
        final AppleRepositoryFactory appleRepositoryFactory = new AppleRepositoryFactory(jdbcAppleRepository, jsonAppleRepository);
        appleService = new AppleService(settings, appleRepositoryFactory);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_findAppleById() {
        // test with jdbc
        settings.setRepositoryType(RepositoryTypeEnum.JDBC);
        assertEquals("JDBC-135", appleService.findAppleById(135l).getMessage());

        // test with json
        settings.setRepositoryType(RepositoryTypeEnum.JSON);
        assertEquals("JSON-243", appleService.findAppleById(243l).getMessage());
    }

    @Test
    public void test_getApples() {
        // test with jdbc
        settings.setRepositoryType(RepositoryTypeEnum.JDBC);
        assertEquals(2, appleService.getApples().size());

        // test with json
        settings.setRepositoryType(RepositoryTypeEnum.JSON);
        assertEquals(3, appleService.getApples().size());
    }

}
```

Comment: The repository pattern is a nice idea but it would involve too many changes if I want to add another persistence-option via plugins. The whole factories would need to be rewritten or they would need some collection where a new kind of persistence (think XML or a certain NoSQL-Database) could "register" itself. But thank you, I thought about the repository pattern for a longer while, but it turns out it's not as flexible as I'd like it to be. Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: i think if you use a dependency injection container like CDI in java then you could replace the factory by producers. and inside this then you could find all beans with implements a specific interface. with this you could create "plugins" for different implementations. then no collection is needed because the container could create the collection by itself with all found beans in the class path with the specific interface.. for example...

Comment: i find this really interesting. if i have the time, i will try this with WELD CDI in my GitHub repository. as i understand you correctly, the goal must be to 1. change on place to change the persistence implementation to one available as "plugin". and second to create a new persistence plugin there must be as few steps as possible to make it available to the application. (usable by the switch property)

Comment: Ya, basically what you said. I want the user to be able to change the persistence layer. So he may say "this project is now in sqlite but now I want it to be saved in .xml instead". Of course old data must be migrated then, but that's not the problem. The thing is, he should be able to change this upon runtime. I will probably not use beans or any other of the few Java constructs I really despise, but thanks for the effort. I can still learn a few things in Java I guess and often I find nifty ways to do the same thing in Scala then :D (for your efforts you get the bounty!)